# Wrong favicon served by nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, favicon

I have a server with two websites, A and B. The nginx configuration for my server is quite basic:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name <url>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:<port>;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Both websites are served just fine, with the exception of website B, who displays the favicon of website A. It works, however, if I try to access website B using `<ip address>:<port>`, so I am pretty sure it's an nginx configuration issue.

I tried all sorts of variants of:

```
location /favicon.ico {
    alias ~/<project folder>/favicon.ico;
}
```

to no avail.

My server runs on ubuntu 16.04, and my websites run on NodeJS.

UPDATE:

I checked the nginx logs and found this:

> 2017/03/07 22:05:58 [error] 7013#7013: *10 open() "`/root/<project_folder>/favicon.ico`" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 37.59.63.164, server: `<url>`, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "`<url>`"

So I guess this is a permission issue on this file. However, I don't understand why this file in particular, as it works for the rest of the folder (including statics) and on the favicon of my second website.

Comment: You only have one server block listed above. Please include configuration for all Nginx server blocks, or explain how you're serving two sites with one server block.

Comment: I have twice the same configuration (in two different files), just replacing the url and port by their respective values.

Comment: Doesn't matter, give us your full config. Also give us a curl showing headers and the matching Nginx access log.

Comment: Do you really use ~ in alias? You gave to use full absolute path

Comment: Usually the favicon need to be in the document root folder. Did you tried to simply put it there without an alias ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen: I changed the path, thanks for the tip. It didn't fix it though.

Comment: @yagmoth555 the favicon is in the document root folder. But for some reason, nginx is looking in the wrong folder.